# Apparently failed GitHub Actions Workflow step shows a hexagon with exclamation mark inside and no logs. What is going on?

Tags: github-actions

My failed GitHub Actions Workflow run appears in the Web UI as follows

[image: GitHub Actions Workflow Web UI]

I cannot figure out a way to see what happened in the CTest step. This step does not offer any logs to expand (the chevron arrow on the left side of the step. If I click the gear icon on top of the page to show Raw Logs, there is nothing there.

The particular Workflow run is at

- https://github.com/skupperproject/skupper-router/actions/runs/6312974752/job/17140289236

What happened and what should I do to see my logs?

Answer (score 0):

In some other job, I noticed

```
Error: Process completed with exit code 143.
```

which lead me to https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6680. Apparently this happens when a CPU-intensive job triggers some internal monitoring alert on GitHub's side, which ends up killing it.

It seems that people were resolving this in various ways

- downgrade to previous Ubuntu runner image, https://github.com/lightninglabs/taproot-assets/commit/beb76bc365e80a8d2bd872fae92f13cb34ef8d6e
- switch to gcc-12 and hope for the best, https://github.com/VROOM-Project/vroom/issues/1002
- tune jvm/javac/kotlinc options to use more memory (and less CPU in trade?) https://github.com/thundernest/k-9/pull/7178/files
- reduce resource usage in each job, e.g. reduce parallelism make `-j` option, split the job into multiple jobs each running subset of tests, https://github.com/medplum/medplum/pull/2521
- the right solution is probably to move to "large runners": https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-larger-runners